# SOMA Command in Datapower

Tags: xslt, ibm-datapower

Am trying to send the below SOMA command  to https://0.0.0.0:5550/service/mgmt/current

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<soapenv:Body> 
<dp:request domain="default">  
    <dp:do-action> 
        <TCPConnectionTest>  
            <RemoteHost>host</RemoteHost> 
            <RemotePort>port</RemotePort> 
        </TCPConnectionTest> 
    </dp:do-action> 
</dp:request> 
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

but getting below response

```
<url-open xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" > 
 <responsecode>500</responsecode> 
 <content-type>text/xml</content-type> 
<headers>  
<header name="Content-Type">text/xml</header> 
<header name="Date">Mon, 06 Mar 2017 05:45:14 GMT</header> 
</headers> 
 <response>  
<env:Envelope> 
    <env:Body>  
        <env:Fault>  
            <faultcode>env:Client</faultcode> 
            <faultstring>Access Denied (from client)</faultstring> 
        </env:Fault> 
    </env:Body> 
</env:Envelope> 
</response> 
</url-open>
```

please help how to get access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use https://127.0.0.1:5550/service/mgmt/current or the real IP for the box. You must also provide a basic auth login (Authorization header) and/or a SSL Proxy (or Client Proxy depending on your firmware)!

If you have setup alias for your NIC's you need to use the alias, e.g.:

`alias 123.123.123.123=MyIP`

Then use:

`https://MyIP:5550/service/mgmt/current`

And of course make sure XML Management is up and running on port 5550 in default domain.

Comment: Hi Anders,
Thx for the response. After passing the Auth header , am able to access CML management interface.